# Can I split the walls?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

Within the Builder base, there are of course, walls. These walls though come in groups of 5 or 10 and seem to be inseparable. Also, when buying new walls, there are in inseparable sets of 5 walls attached to each other. This would disallow flexible base design, something I cannot afford for defensive reasons. As said [here](http://toucharcade.com/2017/05/22/builder-base-update-adds-new-buildings-abilities-troops-and-more-to-clash-of-clans/):

> And there are some new mechanics that should improve the quality of life... walls coming in segments

Is there any way to split the walls into the individual wall pieces (like with the normal base)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to split them apart. They all come in 5 piece sections.